# Change the project type from class library to WPF User control library

Tags: wpf, prism

While setting up my Prism WPF solution I had added a project as Class library. Just realized I want it as a WPF user control library to add resource dictionaries and other WPF related stuff. Is there a way to convert my class library project to WPF user control library project? (Project properties just has the option to convert between Console, Class library, Windows app!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is not an easy change through the project properties (alt+enter). you need to manually edit the .proj file in an editor ( say notepad / textpad) 
when you compare a classlibrary project and a WPF Usercontrol library projects .proj file you will find the difference in them is through the nodes in the  node.

you need to add ProjectTypeGuids , WarningLevel  and  TargetFrameworkProfile . it is my understanding, they started to dictate a project type through the PRojectTypeGuids node! which is really cool!

create a class library project and a WPF usercontrol library project and open the .proj files in an editor to compare, you should be able to figure out what i am talking here!

Comment: @obaylis answer is better, since he mentions the actual GUIDs.

Answer (score 29):

You need to add the following to your project file;

Under the `<FileAlignment>` element

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

You may also want to insure you've the following references added within the `<ItemGroup>` element;

- `<Reference Include="WindowsBase" />`
- `<Reference Include="PresentationCore" />`
- `<Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />`
- `<Reference Include="System.Xaml" />`

Comment: There is a missing ending slash on the last reference (System.Xaml). Without that it won't load correctly.

Comment: Very helpful. Plz note that `<ProjectTypeGuids>` will go at the same level as `<FileAlignment>` node, not under it as described in the answer.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs) for other known GUIDs

Comment: Another difference I noted when comparing a Class Library to a WPF Class Library is the  `<MyType>` element. For a Class Library it was `Windows` and for a WPF Class Library it was `Custom`. Once I changed this in my Class Library project file (along with `ProjectTypeGuids`), the project loaded as WPF Class Library.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy in .Net 6, just enable UseWPF under PropertyGroup, and change TargetFramework node to 'net6.0-windows'. Like below:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
```